# Benchmark test for Java Code

Tags: java, performance, optimization

I am creating a web application in Java, I want to check how efficiently can my code execute?

Are there any benchmark tools for testing Java Code?

Comment: Do you want to do it when the app is in production ? Before ? Do you want to have results for all pages in your application or just specific ones ?

Comment: How do you intent to measure the efficiency of Java code? This can be viewed in many ways. Since Java is a JIT language, you might be interested in how close your Java code performs to a native implementation of the same code. But without a clear metric describing the performance, an answer is hard to provide.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/504103/581205) having some good answers.

Comment: @yannick1976 app is not in production yet

Comment: @yannick1976 i'm just developing the app as a learning experience, so results for just one page at a time will do just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you like to test the whole http call response time you can use tools like [Jmeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/).

It is an open source tool:

> Apache JMeter may be used to test performance both on static and dynamic resources

and again

> You can use it to make a graphical analysis of performance or to test your server/script/object behavior under heavy concurrent load.

In the past I used it when I worked in a team responsible for performances of a big italian web site.

Comment: I don't know why this question is put on hold

Comment: Should I edit the question or Do I need to post the code, but I dont have any problem in my code :(

Comment: I just needed some suggestions

Comment: @Davide_Lorenzo_Marino  thank you :) appreciate it